# how to validate my password in combination of lettters numaric and special class in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

am using angular validation in my login form.  How to set password field validation in the combination of special character, letters, and numbers. so anyone can help me how to set my password?

my HTML code is,

```
        <div ng-app="loginApp">
         <div ng-controller="loginController">
          <div class="container">
               <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="submit()">
                  <h3>Log In</h3>
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <label>User Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                  id="username" ng-model="obj.username">
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" 
          id="pass" ng-model="obj.password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                      Log In</button> 
                    </div>
                    </form>
            </form>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

my controller is,

```
    angular.module('loginApp',[])
    .controller('loginController',function($scope){
    $scope.obj={};

    $scope.submit=function(){
        alert('submit');
        console.log( $scope.obj);
    }

    })
```

Comment: You can check the password strength with [`zxcvbn` module](https://github.com/ghostbar/angular-zxcvbn)

Answer (score 1):

Hi yazhini k you can check the strength of your password as follows:

```js
angular.module('loginApp',[])
    .controller('loginController',function($scope){
    $scope.obj={};
    

    $scope.submit=function(){
        if((!/\d/.test($scope.obj.password))){
        alert("password must contain digits");
        }
        if(!/[A-Z]/.test($scope.obj.password)){
        alert("password must contain uppercase letter");
        }
        if(!/[a-z]/.test($scope.obj.password)){
        alert("password must contain lowercase letter");
        }
        if(!/[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/.test($scope.obj.password)){
        alert("password must contain special character");
        }
        console.log( $scope.obj);
    }

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="loginApp">
         <div ng-controller="loginController">
          <div class="container">
               <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="submit()">
                  <h3>Log In</h3>
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <label>User Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                  id="username" ng-model="obj.username">
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" 
          id="pass" ng-model="obj.password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                      Log In</button> 
                    </div>
                    </form>
            </form>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function validatePassword(str) {
            var code, i, len;
            for (i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
                code = str.charCodeAt(i);
                if (!(code > 47 && code < 58) &&    // numeric (0-9)
                    !(code > 64 && code < 91) &&    // upper alpha (A-Z)
                    !(code > 96 && code < 123) &&   // lower alpha (a-z)
                    !(code == 32) &&    // space ( )
                    !(code == 45))      // dash (-)
                    // Extend your acceptable special characters here
                    {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        },
```